# How can I get "Attach Article" of "Insert Article into Email" from Knowledge search results

Tags: case, knowledge

How can I get "Attach Article" of "Insert Article into Email" from Knowledge search results from a Case?

On Case, Articles can be added from "suggested Articles".  Is there a way to do the same with Knowledge Search results?

How can we link an article from Knowledge search result to a Case?

[image: How can I get "Attach Article" of "Insert Article into Email" from Knowledge search results from a Case?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You cannot attach an article from the *search result dropdown* as you're typing as your screenshot shows.
- You can attach articles using the dropdown next to the articles from the *search results* when you complete your search.

[Use the Lightning Knowledge Component](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.knowledge_lightning_sidebar.htm&type=5)

> Attach and Remove Articles in the Knowledge Component
>
> Agents can attach Knowledge articles to cases and remove articles from cases using the dropdown next to any article.

As such, you need to do the following:

1. Type your search string
2. Press enter
3. Now the *search results* display instead of the "Suggestions"
4. Click dropdown on desired article & select "attach article"

[image]